# How to merge 2 serializable functions into 1 serializable function in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, serialization, closures, stringification

As you know, there are certain cases (e.g., use in workers) when functions need to be serializable (and, at the other side, deserializable of course). I have such a case; a library function (i.e. I cannot change it) `doSomething(serializableFunction)` expects such a function from me. Also it expects that `serializableFunction` accepts 1 parameter `x` and gives `x` to it.

So far, this was not a problem for me; I had one function `f(x)` from another library that fulfilled my purposes (so I just called `doSomething(f)` so far). But now, I have a second serializable function `g(x)`, also from a library, and I want the function I give to `doSomething` to execute either `f` or `g`, dependent on `x`. So I tried:

```
doSomething(function h(x) {
  if (x < 5) return f(x);
  else return g(x);
});
```

This would work well without serialization, but with it, an error is thrown of course because `h` is not serializable anymore: It calls `f` and `g`, which are no longer known at deserialization time!

So currently I'm doing:

```
doSomething(eval(`function h(x) {
  const f = ${f.toString()};
  const g = ${g.toString()};
  if (x < 5) return f(x);
  else return g(x);
}`));
```

This works, but it's a nightmare! So my question is: Is there any better approach to merge 2 serializable functions (like `f`and `g`) into 1 function that is also serializable? Note that I cannot change any of `f`, `g`, or `doSomething`, just `h`!

Comment: What do you need to pass in `doSomething`? a string or a function?

Comment: @ikhvjs: A serializable function.

Comment: Um...,Let me ask this way. What is type of the argument of the `doSomething`? A string or A function?

Comment: A function. This function is then internally serialized to a string by `doSomething` I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I think of a solution replacing `eval` with `new Funciton`.
Not the best, but a bit better.

Example below:

```js
function f(a) {
    console.log("f", a);
}

function g(b) {
    console.log("f", b);
}

function doSomething(func) {
    const y = 1;
    func(y);
}

const funcBody = `return function () {
    const f = ${f.toString()};
    const g = ${g.toString()};
    if (x < 5) return f(x);
    else return g(x);
  }()`;

const func = new Function("x", funcBody);

doSomething(func);
```

Or you can add some abstraction like below:

```js
function f(a) {
    console.log("f", a);
}

function g(b) {
    console.log("f", b);
}

function doSomething(func) {
    const y = 1;
    func(y);
}

const getFuncArray = (name = "x") => [
    name,
    `return function () {
        const f = ${f.toString()};
        const g = ${g.toString()};
        if (${name} < 5) return f(${name});
        else return g(${name});
    }()`,
];

const res = new Function(...getFuncArray());

doSomething(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a better version of my approach but the main point - having to stringify and "concatenate" `f` and `g` in a stringified `h` - is still not solved. I thought there may be a standard way or at least a library to accomplish this task, as it should be pretty frequent.

Comment: @Remirror, apparently if `doSomething` lose the scope chain of the js you executed, it means whatever variable reference you pass to `doSomething` would be lost. I guess `doSomething` is like a callback function in your case.

Comment: You may imagine you try to call a `callback` function, if you have a variable reference from an outer scope, the time you call the `callback` cannot touch the variable reference in the outer scope anymore.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I too think that's the problem. But how to solve it? I'm imagining something like handing over `f` and `g` as arguments to `h` but wrapping `h` in another function; however, then the same problem would occur.

Comment: @Remirror, can you change the `doSomething` like `const newDoSomething = doSomething.bind(null,arg1,arg2);` ?? Then, you call `newDoSomething` instead?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: @Remirror, I think there is no other way as you have no control of the `doSomething`.